# How can I go to an address when I click on the logout button

Tags: php

I wrote the following code and I think my `logout.php` file is correct. Also when I click on the `logout` button I can destroy the all sessions. But I can not go  to  an address like the `https://www.google.com` address.

**logout.php file:**

```
﻿<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) 
{
$go = "https://www.google.com";
header("Location: $go"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: try `header("Location: ".$go); `?

Comment: _But I can not go to an address_ - Did you see a white page? php errors?

Comment: turn on `error reporting`

Comment: put a die("Ok session destroy is working"); inside the if block and see if 'Ok session destroy is working' gets printed out.